# What is the difference between Step Into vs Step Over options in the Oracle SQL Developer tool?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I couldn't understand what is the difference between Step Into and Step Over options in the SQL Developer.
[image]

I know the difference between Step Into and Step Over buttons in the Toolbar while debugging a PL/SQL program as shown in the image below.

[image]

But, I want to ask you to these 2 options in the Preferences tools.

It seems like there is no difference when I chose both of them.

Could you clarify this confusion?

Comment: Any ideas @thatjeffsmith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first debugger instruction is determined by this setting.

If you set it to Run until breakpoint, and you have no breakpoints or exceptions, the debugger will rip right through your program, and it will look like to the user that it's 'not working'

In older versions of SQL Developer, step into by default would start you in the Anonymous block of pl/sql used to kick off your procedure, and step over would start you on line 1 of the program being debugged.

In the current version, i'm the same as you - I can't observe any difference between the two options. This may be a bug...